# OnSelectedIndexChanged event is not firing

Tags: vb.net

Here is the .aspx code snippet.

```
                <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td class="sectionHeading">
                       Dashboard</td>
                    <td> Division &nbsp: &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivisions" runat="server" `enter code     here`OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDivisions_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="152px">
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>
                </tr>
```

Below is my databinding code. It is called from Page_Load()

```
'Populate Diviions dropdown
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddlDivisions.DataSource = Divisions.Fetch().List
        ddlDivisions.DataTextField = "DivisionDesc"
        ddlDivisions.DataValueField = "DivisionID"
        ddlDivisions.SelectedValue = 3  'Divisioon All
        ddlDivisions.DataBind()
    End If
```

Below is my event handler...

```
  Protected Sub ddlDivisions_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlDivisions.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Other code goes here
  End Sub
```

Above event handler is not getting called. I have done so far below things as part of    my    research

1. Bind data to datasource of dropdown control when it is not postback
2. Control was added from toolbox
3. tried adding event handler in .aspx. Still did not work.

Comment: Show us the markup. #3 is likely your problem.

Comment: Does your event handler need to be `Public`, not `Protected`? Also, if you have a Handles statement on the method, you don't also need to add it into the markup. Pick one or the other.

Answer (score 6):

Your markup for the DropDownList does not specify the [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) attribute. This is required to be present and set to true (the default is false):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivisions" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDivisions_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="152px">
</asp:DropDownList>
```